# jquery exit function in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to exit a function, depending on the result of an `GET` request.

For example, in the below function, `hi`, if the `GET` results in `data`, where `data === '1'`, I want to exit the function.

```
function hi () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/shop/haveItem",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == '1') {
                // exit hi() function
            }
        }
    });
    // some executable code when data is not '1'
}
```

How can I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the solution can be something like this

```
function hi () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/shop/haveItem",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == '1') {
                ifData1();
            } else {
                ifDataNot1()
            }
        }
    });
}
function ifData1 () { /* etc */ }
function ifDataNot1 () { /* etc */ }
```

If you have an ajax function, you should always work with callback functions. If you make an ajax function synchronous, then the browser will be blocked for the duration of ajax call. Which means that the application will remain non-responsive during the duration of the call.

Comment: Sorry, a copy mistake I think, I'll remove it

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to return false to simulate "exit".

```
function hi()
{
    $.ajax({
            url: "/shop/haveItem",
            type: "GET",
            async:false,
            success: function(data){
                if(data == '1')
                    return false
            }
        });

    //some executable code when data is not '1'
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think this is one of the best answer. It works and it's simple.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is have a flag variable. Assign it to true or false, depending on if you want to exit or not.

```
function hi()
{
var flag=false;    
$.ajax({
            url: "/shop/haveItem",
            type: "GET",
            async:false,
            success: function(data){
                if(data == '1')
                    flag=true;
            }
        });
if ( flag ) return;
    //some executable code when data is not '1'
    ...
}
```

Comment: Making an ajax call `asynch` may not be the best solution. It will block the application for the duration of the ajax call

Comment: unless async false, falg variable can not catch ajax return value. but i also think I'd better finding another solution

Answer (score 0):

Creating a global flag variable I think would work the best. Tested and working!!

```
window.flag = [];

function hi()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "/shop/haveItem",
        type: "GET",
        async:false,
        success: function(data){
            if(data == '1')
                flag = true;
        }
    });

    if (flag) {
        return false; 
    }


//some executable code when data is not '1'
...
}
```